# Setup Routing between AP and STA in WIFI_AP_STA

Tags: c++, esp8266

I am trying to setup routing or some interface between between AP and STA of the ESP8266 in my nodeMCU. I am trying to Setup a Wifi Repeater in NAT mode.   Here is the code I have written,

```
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
  #include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
  const char* ssid = "********";
  const char* password = "********";

  /* Settings for SSID to be forwarded*/

  IPAddress staticIP(192,168,1,113);
  IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
  IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

  MDNSResponder mdns;
  WiFiServer server(80);


  int i=0;

  void setup(void)
  {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
    /*Station Mode Configuration*/
    Serial.printf("Connecting to %s\n", ssid);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    WiFi.config(staticIP, gateway, subnet);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.print("MAC Address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
    Serial.print("Gateway IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.gatewayIP());
    Serial.print("DNS Server: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.dnsIP());

    /*SoftAP configuration */

    //Serial.print("Setting soft-AP configuration ... ");
    //Serial.println(WiFi.softAPConfig(local_IP, gateway, subnet) ? "Ready" : "Failed!");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Setting soft-AP ... ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.softAP("ESPsoftAP_01") ? "Ready" : "Failed!");

    Serial.print("Soft-AP IP address = ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
  }

  void loop()
  {
    int j = WiFi.softAPgetStationNum();
    if(j != i)
    {
      Serial.printf("Stations connected to soft-AP = %d\n", WiFi.softAPgetStationNum());
      i = j;
    }


/* Checks for the requests from the ESP clients and prints them on the serial monitor. */
    mdns.update();   // Check for any mDNS queries and send responses

    WiFiClient client = server.available();  // Check if a client has connected
    if (client)
    {
      Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("New client");
    Serial.println("Checkpoint 0");

    // Wait for data from client to become available
    while (client.connected() && !client.available())
    {
      delay(1);
    }
    Serial.println("Checkpoint 1");
    // Read the first line of HTTP request
    String req = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.println(req);
    }
  }
```

I am able to connect ESP to my Wifi and also able to connect some stations to the ESP. But Unfortunately, I am having no luck transferring the request and response between the Clients of ESP and the Internet.

**The Problem:** In the last section, `checkpoint 0` is not getting printed which means clients is returning false. But according to this part

```
    int j = WiFi.softAPgetStationNum();
    if(j != i)
    {
      Serial.printf("Stations connected to soft-AP = %d\n", WiFi.softAPgetStationNum());
      i = j;
    }
```

Client is getting connected. Why is it so?

**OUTPUT:**

```
 Connecting to ********
 .......
 Connected, IP address: 192.168.1.113
 MAC Address: **:**:**:**:**:**
 Gateway IP: 192.168.1.1
 DNS Server: 0.0.0.0

 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

 Setting soft-AP ... Ready
 Soft-AP IP address = 192.168.4.1
 Stations connected to soft-AP = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a great idea but the network stack on the ESP8266 is unable to route packets or perform NAT.

The code you've written is trying to act as a proxy, not a router.

A router copies IP packets between network interfaces - it's able to route all protocols that run over IP. NAT rewrites the IP addresses of some of the packets in order to hide the network that's being NATed. The ESP8266 network stack isn't able to do this.

Your code is creating a TCP-based server on port 80 - the web port. It will only be able to proxy TCP packets to port 80 - it won't be able to proxy name server requests or any other protocols.

Proxies are a lot more complicated than you might think. HTTP requires the addition of proxy headers. Proxying encrypted connections is also more complicated and requires listening on port 443. And the client must be configured to know to connect to the proxy server, which must be able to inspect the original request in order to know where to connect to for it.

The ESP8266 network stack is only capable of 5 simultaneous TCP connections. If the original connection is coming from a web browser, web browsers commonly open many more than 5 connections at a time as web pages often pull in CSS, Javascript and images from many locations. And remember that each proxied connection will require an outgoing connection, so proxying even 2 TCP connections will use up 4 of the 5 available. The limitation of 5 simultaneous connections means that  an ESP8266 will not be able to successfully act as a proxy for a web browser.

There's a difference between a Wifi client and a TCP client. I wish the Arduino and ESP8266 SDKs had been more clear on their naming here. `WiFiServer` actually has nothing to do with WiFi - it's a TCP server.

You're not seeing a connection "Checkpoint 0" here because whatever it is that you're trying to route/proxy doesn't know to open a TCP connection to your ESP8266 (assuming it's even trying to use TCP at all).

It's a nice try but unfortunately the ESP8266 is not suitable for this kind of use.

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation. I am able to contemplate your point. However, there is a project on Github which is able to perform the same action. It's source code is not disclosed (Irony). Kindly, look at this link. https://github.com/martin-ger/esp_wifi_repeater

Comment: That project does not use the Arduino SDK. It looks like it includes its own network stack (in binary not source). If you want to write your on network stack, yes, you can could route packets and do NAT. Unfortunately, the Arduino SDK doesn’t come close to letting you do that.

Comment: Are you aware of  any boards or networking stack available in the market that I could use to achieve my task?

Comment: I would just use a Raspberry Pi Zero W. $10, runs real Linux so it's easy to build a router, NAT, firewall, etc. I'm not 100% certain it can run as both an AP and station at the same time so it might need an additional USB wifi interface.

Comment: Yes, you can run AP + STA mode in RPi Zero W, but the connection is not stable (responsive)